# ¿Cómo usar Hydra en Kali Linux con un formulario Ajax?

Tags: ajax, kali-linux

**CONTEXTO.**
Tengo un sitio web que contiene un formulario de inicio de sesión que funciona con Ajax jQuery. Estoy usando Burp Suite para interceptar peticiones a este formulario. Burp Suite devuelve esto cuando intento iniciar sesión:

```
POST /php/process.php HTTP/2
Host: mydomain.com
Cookie: PHPSESSID=d123456e4a12345678c7ebb3af134720
Content-Length: 351
Sec-Ch-Ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96"
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryI8Sgucep9yRmKinT
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Linux"
Origin: https://mydomain.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://mydomain.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

------WebKitFormBoundaryI8Sgucep9yRmKinT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"
admin

------WebKitFormBoundaryI8Sgucep9yRmKinT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pass"
abc123

------WebKitFormBoundaryI8Sgucep9yRmKinT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form"
login

------WebKitFormBoundaryI8Sgucep9yRmKinT--
```

**PROBLEMA.**
Cuando el formulario no es Ajax, el cuerpo de la petición viene así: `user=admin&pass=abc123&form=login`, y el siguiente comando [Hydra](https://www.kali.org/tools/hydra/) funciona perfectamente:

```
hydra mydomain.com -l admin -P passwords.txt https-post-form "/php/process.php:user=^USER^&pass=^PASS^&form=login:Error login"
```

Pero en el presente caso (con mi formulario Ajax), el cuerpo de la petición es muy distinto:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryI8Sgucep9yRmKinT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"
admin
etc...
```

...y el mismo comando Hydra ya no funciona como se espera, porque ahora dice que todos los passwords son correctos, lo cual no es cierto.

¿Cómo usar Hydra en Kali Linux con mi formulario Ajax?

¡Saludos!

Comment: fíjate que en el header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;` debiera ser `application/json`